# lvm commands report no data after lvextend

Tags: partitioning, lvm, lvmcache

Had a weird issue happen yesterday on our Ubuntu 18.04 server. One of the team tried to add 30G of space to this LV:

```
Disk /dev/mapper/rootvg-pgexecstsqllv: 32 GiB, 34359738368 bytes, 67108864 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
```

The system is supposed to have one volume group (rootvg), but after they proceeded with the lvextend and resize2fs commands, the system stopped showing all values from the pvscan, vgscan, lvscan. Here's an example with vgscan with verbose on. This system is supposed to have one volume group called rootvg. Reading the cache reports "No volume groups found."

```
vgscan -vv
      devices/global_filter not found in config: defaulting to global_filter = [ "a|.*/|" ]
      Setting global/locking_type to 1
      Setting global/use_lvmetad to 1
      global/lvmetad_update_wait_time not found in config: defaulting to 10
      Setting response to OK
      Setting protocol to lvmetad
      Setting version to 1
      Setting global/use_lvmpolld to 1
      Setting devices/sysfs_scan to 1
      Setting devices/multipath_component_detection to 1
      Setting devices/md_component_detection to 1
      Setting devices/fw_raid_component_detection to 0
      Setting devices/ignore_suspended_devices to 0
      Setting devices/ignore_lvm_mirrors to 1
      devices/filter not found in config: defaulting to filter = [ "a|.*/|" ]
      Setting devices/cache_dir to /run/lvm
      Setting devices/cache_file_prefix to
      devices/cache not found in config: defaulting to /run/lvm/.cache
      Setting devices/write_cache_state to 1
      Setting global/use_lvmetad to 1
      Setting activation/activation_mode to degraded
      metadata/record_lvs_history not found in config: defaulting to 0
      Setting activation/monitoring to 1
      Setting global/locking_type to 1
      Setting global/wait_for_locks to 1
      File-based locking selected.
      Setting global/prioritise_write_locks to 1
      Setting global/locking_dir to /run/lock/lvm
      Setting global/use_lvmlockd to 0
      Locking /run/lock/lvm/P_global WB
    Wiping cache of LVM-capable devices
    Wiping internal VG cache
      Setting response to OK
      Setting token to filter:3239235440
      Setting daemon_pid to 665
      Setting response to OK
      Setting global_disable to 0
  Reading volume groups from cache.
      Setting response to OK
      Setting response to OK
      Setting response to OK
    No volume groups found.
      Unlocking /run/lock/lvm/P_global
      Setting global/notify_dbus to 1
```

The commands are reporting that it can no longer see the PVs, LVs, and VGs. Even though the system is still up and running and the device files appear to be intact.

```
ls -ld /dev/rootvg /dev/rootvg/* /dev/mapper/root* /dev/dm*
brw-rw---- 1 root disk 253,  0 Jul 13 22:07 /dev/dm-0
brw-rw---- 1 root disk 253,  1 Jul 13 22:07 /dev/dm-1
brw-rw---- 1 root disk 253, 10 Jul 13 22:07 /dev/dm-10
brw-rw---- 1 root disk 253, 11 Jul 13 22:07 /dev/dm-11
brw-rw---- 1 root disk 253,  2 Jul 13 22:07 /dev/dm-2
brw-rw---- 1 root disk 253,  3 Jul 13 22:07 /dev/dm-3
brw-rw---- 1 root disk 253,  4 Jul 13 22:07 /dev/dm-4
brw-rw---- 1 root disk 253,  5 Jul 13 22:07 /dev/dm-5
brw-rw---- 1 root disk 253,  6 Jul 13 22:07 /dev/dm-6
brw-rw---- 1 root disk 253,  7 Jul 13 22:07 /dev/dm-7
brw-rw---- 1 root disk 253,  8 Jul 13 22:07 /dev/dm-8
brw-rw---- 1 root disk 253,  9 Jul 13 22:07 /dev/dm-9
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root       7 Jul 13 22:07 /dev/mapper/rootvg-appslv -> ../dm-2
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root       7 Jul 13 22:07 /dev/mapper/rootvg-execdirstsqllv -> ../dm-6
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root       7 Jul 13 22:07 /dev/mapper/rootvg-execstsqlddlv -> ../dm-8
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root       8 Jul 13 22:07 /dev/mapper/rootvg-inbacklv -> ../dm-10
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root       7 Jul 13 22:07 /dev/mapper/rootvg-nodeapplv -> ../dm-9
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root       7 Jul 13 22:07 /dev/mapper/rootvg-pgarcloglv -> ../dm-4
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root       7 Jul 13 22:07 /dev/mapper/rootvg-pgbackuplv -> ../dm-3
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root       7 Jul 13 22:07 /dev/mapper/rootvg-pgexecstsqllv -> ../dm-5
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root       7 Jul 13 22:07 /dev/mapper/rootvg-rootlv -> ../dm-0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root       8 Jul 13 22:07 /dev/mapper/rootvg-tempfslv -> ../dm-11
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root       7 Jul 13 22:07 /dev/mapper/rootvg-tmplv -> ../dm-1
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root       7 Jul 13 22:07 /dev/mapper/rootvg-workdirlv -> ../dm-7
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root     280 Jul 13 20:32 /dev/rootvg
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root       7 Jul 13 22:07 /dev/rootvg/appslv -> ../dm-2
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root       7 Jul 13 22:07 /dev/rootvg/execdirstsqllv -> ../dm-6
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root       7 Jul 13 22:07 /dev/rootvg/execstsqlddlv -> ../dm-8
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root       8 Jul 13 22:07 /dev/rootvg/inbacklv -> ../dm-10
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root       7 Jul 13 22:07 /dev/rootvg/nodeapplv -> ../dm-9
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root       7 Jul 13 22:07 /dev/rootvg/pgarcloglv -> ../dm-4
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root       7 Jul 13 22:07 /dev/rootvg/pgbackuplv -> ../dm-3
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root       7 Jul 13 22:07 /dev/rootvg/pgexecstsqllv -> ../dm-5
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root       7 Jul 13 22:07 /dev/rootvg/rootlv -> ../dm-0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root       8 Jul 13 22:07 /dev/rootvg/tempfslv -> ../dm-11
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root       7 Jul 13 22:07 /dev/rootvg/tmplv -> ../dm-1
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root       7 Jul 13 22:07 /dev/rootvg/workdirlv -> ../dm-7
```

It appears as if the LVM cache or similar has been corrupted or has gone missing. It looks like this has happened to others before, as I found a series of similar questions. This one appeared promising:
https://superuser.com/questions/421896/vgdisplay-and-lvdisplay-no-volume-groups-found

Unfortunately it did not resolve the issue. Does anyone have an idea how to rebuild the LVM cache? Is there anything other than a re-install that can fix this?

Thx,

Steve

Comment: [Ubuntu 18.04 LTS has reached the end of it's *standard* support life](https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2023/05/13/extended-security-maintenance-for-ubuntu-18-04-bionic-beaver-begins-31-may-2023/) thus is now off-topic here unless your question is specific to helping you move to a *fully supported* release of Ubuntu.  Ubuntu 18.04 ESM support is available, but not on-topic here, see https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic  See also https://ubuntu.com//blog/18-04-end-of-standard-support

Comment: I understand. My only concern and reason for posting is that this is the third time I see this type of thing happening, and it does not appear to be rev-dependent. I had it happen in 16.04 and had to rebuild the system from scratch. And also had this occur in 20.04, but yet to see it in 22.04, it just so happened that the latest occurrence was on a server I was expecting to upgrade later this month.

Answer (score 0):

A reboot (even into recovery mode) was leaving us at a maintenance shell, with the message "rootvg does not exist", despite the fact that the /dev files all showed normal. What was missing was all the /dev/dm* files associated with /dev/mapper.

I suspect that the lvextend that was done by the operator may have overwritten another section of the O/S disk storage where the rootvg volume group information was stored. Checking the history, the commands that they did appeared normal. The only mistake I noted was trying to do the lvextend and resize2fs as the non-root user (did not sudo).

Long story short, we were again not able to recover this system. The pvscan/vgscan was about all that was suggested and with -vvv flag, it indicated that the problem was likely the cache. This has happened twice before, making me question the reliability of the LVM in Ubuntu 16, 18, and 20.

We have rebuilt this system with Ubuntu 22.04, and then restored our PostgreSQL database that was in use on that system from a nightly backup. I wish we could have figured out what causes this, as it appears to be something that has been reported at least 3-4 times before as I observed from Google searches. Just no one had a solution or even a suggestion on what to check, and this server could not be left in the state it was. It was needed by end of the day.

We are now going to have two servers with PostgreSQL streaming replication in place (should have had that already!) and so if it happens again we can take the machine out of service and try to analyze it more, while not impacting our users.